# How do I calculate duration between the dates in Confluence

Tags: confluence, confluence-macros

I am trying to display duration column with difference between 2 dates in Confluence.
I have tried below:

select *,(CAST(ROUND(ceiling(DATEDIFF(DAY,'From Date','To Date')))as int))+1+ " days" as 'Duration' from T1

this gives the result, however given the dates 25-Jun-2020 to 26-Jun-2020 - duration displayed as 1 instead of 2.

your help is appreciated here. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select *,('To Date' - 'From Date' + "24h") / "24h" + " days" as 'Duration' from T1

this works perfectly with below settings in confluence

365 days in a year
7 days a week
24 hours in a day
dd.mm.yy
points,